# SignalR client function not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

### Overview

I am having real problems getting my SignalR server/hub to call a javascript function on my SignalR client.

### What I have tried

- I have read more tutorials and viewed so many examples (including the official docs) of how this should work that it is almost ridiculous.
- I have tried commenting out all but the core functionality.
- I have ensure that the server and client functions are not the same and spelt correctly.
- I have turned logging on also but no errors have appeared in the Firebug console.

### Enviornment

The SignalR code in question has been implemented in an ASP.net MVC4 project using VB.net with MySQL and Entity framework v5. I am debugging the system on my local development machine in Visual Studio 2012 with IISExpress.

### Code snippets

**global.asax.vb:**

```
Sub Application_Start()

    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize()

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

    ' Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth()

    ' Register custom view
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(New CustomViewEngine())

End Sub
```

**SignalR initialisation javascript:**

```
$(function () {

    // Proxy created on the fly
    var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
    //$.connection.notificationHub.logging = true;

    // Declare functions that can be run on the client by the server
    notification.client.sendNotification = onAddNotification;

    // Testing code only
    $("#testButton").click(function () {
        // Run test function on server
        notification.server.runTest();
    });

    // Map the onConnect and onDisconnect functions
    notification.client.connected = function () { };
    notification.client.disconnected = function () { };

    //$.connection.hub.start();
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        alert("Notification system connected");
    });
});

// Process a newly received notification from the server
function onAddNotification(message) {

    // Convert the passed json message back into an object
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);

    var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(obj.Timestamp.substr(6)));

    // Update the notification list
    $('#notifications').prepend('<li>' + obj.Message + ' at ' + dateFormat(parsedDate, "default") + '</li>');

    // Update the new notification count
    var count = document.getElementById("notification_count")
    if (count.textContent) {
        //W3C DOM
        count.textContent = obj.Count;
    } else if (anchor.innerText) {
        //Microsoft DOM
        count.innerText = obj.Count;
    }
    //document.getElementById("notification_count").innerHTML = obj.Count + '<i class="splashy-comment"></i>';

    // Show a brief notification message
    $.sticky(obj.Message, { autoclose: 2000, position: "top-right", type: "st-info" });

};
```

**Hub class:**

```
Public Class NotificationHub
Inherits Hub

ReadOnly Group As String = "Notification"

Public Function RunTest()
    Dim testMessage As New SignalR_Notification_Message

    testMessage.Count = 3
    testMessage.Message = "Some test message"
    testMessage.Timestamp = Now

    Call Notify(testMessage, "joebloggs")
End Function

Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task

    Dim db As New MyEntities
    Dim userName As String = Context.User.Identity.Name
    Dim connectionID = Context.ConnectionId

    Dim conn As SignalR_Connection

    ' Attempt to find a retrieve a connection entry with the same Connection ID
    conn = db.SignalR_Connection.Where(Function(s) s.Connection_ID = connectionID).FirstOrDefault

    ' If the connection does not already exist, add it
    If IsNothing(conn) Then
        conn = New SignalR_Connection

        ' Create the new connection entry
        conn.Connection_ID = connectionID
        conn.Username = userName
        conn.Group = Group

        ' Attempt to save the new connection entry
        Try
            db.SignalR_Connection.Add(conn)
            db.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim a As String = ""
            a = ""
        End Try
    End If

    Return MyBase.OnConnected()
End Function

Public Overrides Function OnDisconnected() As Task

    Dim db As New MyEntities
    Dim userName As String = Context.User.Identity.Name
    Dim connectionId As String = Context.ConnectionId

    Dim conn As SignalR_Connection

    ' Attempt to find a retrieve the connection entry
    conn = db.SignalR_Connection.Where(Function(s) s.Connection_ID = connectionId And s.Username = userName).FirstOrDefault

    ' Attempt to remove the connection entry
    Try
        db.SignalR_Connection.Remove(conn)
        db.SaveChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim a As String = ""
        a = ""
    End Try

    Return MyBase.OnDisconnected()
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Send the notification to the client
''' </summary>
Public Sub Notify(Message As SignalR_Notification_Message, Username As String)

    Dim ConnectionIDs As List(Of String)
    Dim Serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim json As String

    ' Attempt to convert the object into json before sending
    Try
        json = Serializer.Serialize(Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    ' Get the connection id's this message must go to
    ConnectionIDs = GetUsersConnectionID(Username)

    If Not IsNothing(ConnectionIDs) Then
        ' Send the message to all connection ID's
        For Each ConnectionID In ConnectionIDs
            Clients.Client(ConnectionID).sendNotification(json)
        Next
    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Retrieve a list of connection ID's for the current user
''' </summary>
Public Function GetUsersConnectionID(Username As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim db As New MyEntities

    ' Attempt to find a retrieve the connection entries
    Return db.SignalR_Connection.AsNoTracking.Where(Function(s) s.Username = Username).Select(Function(s) s.Connection_ID).ToList

End Function

End Class
```

**HTML (Partial View):**

```
@ModelType Geo_sight.NotificationWindowModel

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myNotifications">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Notifications</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="unstyled" id="notifications">
        @For Each Notification In Model.Notifications
            @<li>@Html.Raw(Notification.Text)</li>
        Next
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" id="testButton">Send test</a>
</div>
```

### The problem

With a breakpoint set on the first line of the *onAddNotification* function:

> var obj = JSON.parse(message);

Whenever the *Notify* function in the Hub is called the client function is practically never called!

### Other useful bits

1. The connection is definitely successful as I can see the connections long-polling in Firebug.
2. My user connections are being successfully saved and retrieved from my database in the *onConnected* and *GetUsersConnectionID* functions.
3. Of the dozens and dozens of times I have tried to run the client function from the server (using the *testButton* to fire off the notification call on the hub), it has run no more than 3-4 times, neither times of which I have been able to repeat.
4. On the very rare and random occasion that the function has run, it has done what it is supposed to do and I have been able to halt execution of the function with a breakpoint in the client.
5. I have checked my *~/signalr/hubs* script and there is nothing listed under the client function definitions, but is for the server (see below). Is this correct? I'd imagine the client functions should be here?

   ```
   proxies.notificationHub = this.createHubProxy('notificationHub'); 
   proxies.notificationHub.client = { };
   proxies.notificationHub.server = {
       getUsersConnectionID: function (Username) {
           return proxies.notificationHub.invoke.apply(proxies.notificationHub, $.merge(["GetUsersConnectionID"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
        },

       notify: function (Message, Username) {
           return proxies.notificationHub.invoke.apply(proxies.notificationHub, $.merge(["Notify"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
        },

       runTest: function () {
           return proxies.notificationHub.invoke.apply(proxies.notificationHub, $.merge(["RunTest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
        }
   };

   return proxies;
   ```

---

### Update 2013-04-04

With a little more debugging, I can make the client run but completely randomly and very occassionally simply by pressing my test button again and again a few seconds after the previous signalR send call finishes.

Here is an example of this from the Firebug console...
[image: Firebug console]

---

### Update 2013-04-05

With more and more testing and debugging, I have come across a trait in when the client function does and doesn't call...

As can be seen in my previous update, SignalR has chosen to use Long-polling with a time-out of about 35 seconds.

Having made a number of further repeated calls to the client function, it seems that only the calls made within approximately the first 10 seconds of a long-polls life reach the client and run the function successfully. The calls sent after this period don't seem to come through.

I guess this means my code is sound but why is this happening??

**SignalR FAQ question...**

I also found something similair to my issue here: [SignalR Wiki FAQ's](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq#why-does-signalr-stop-accepting-connections-after-10-or-so)

I am using Windows 7 Professional but i'm not using IIS (im using IIS Express), so could this be the same issue?

Comment: Hi John. Your SignalR implementation seems to be OK. I have tested your code with a simple web app and it works fine for me. You can download it at https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByKkLqyN2n_saGVObjlrLTR3U1U/edit?usp=sharing. Have you checked that the connectionIds match and are not being truncated?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this, it is very much appreciated!
I have checked the connection ID's and they are definitely the same so no issues there. Strangely, the project you made runs just fine and all messages to the client get through, so something is playing up somewhere.